# How to fix 'ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant someController)' error in ruby on rails 5

Tags: controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes, rails-api

I'm working on an API that takes specific data, creates a pdf and sends it in an email using rails 5. After setting up my routes/controllers/model I keep getting `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant InfluencerreportsController).`

I've surfed the web trying to find the solution, and while there are many others with the same error, none of their solutions worked out for me. As far as I could tell, the error means my file names and the controller don't match, but there are no typos anywhere. I'm aware of the error message saying `InfluencerreportsController` but I tried changing my controller to that name and that did nothing. Would I possibly have to change it in other locations also?

Another thing worth mentioning is that I used rails generate for everything (contollers, models, and migrations), so I didn't create any of the files myself.

This is my first time dealing with `nested_attributes`, so I'm not sure if I did it correctly or if that could be causing the problem.

Thank you in advance!

**Here is my project directory:**

I'm not able to post images because of a lack of reputation, but my controller filename is `influencer_reports_controller.rb`

**influencer_reports_controller.rb:**

```
class InfluencerReportsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @report = InfluencerReport.create!(influencerreport_params)
    json_response(@report, :created)
  end

  private

  def influencerreport_params
    params.require(:influencerreport).permit(:instagram_handle,
                                             :email,
                                             :city,
                                             :post_price_by_category,
                                       :post_price_by_category_engagements,
                                         :post_price_by_avg_engagements,
                                         photos_attributes: [
                                           :industry,
                                           :likes,
                                           :comments
                                           ])
  end
end
```

**influencer_report_model.rb:**

```
class InfluencerReport < ApplicationRecord
  # model assocation
  has_many :photos, inverse_of: :influencerreport

  # validations
  validates_presence_of :instagram_handle,
                        :email,
                        :city,
                        :post_price_by_category,
                    :post_price_by_category_engagements,
                    :post_price_by_avg_engagements

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  resources :influencerreports, only: [:create] do
    resources :photos, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

**error message:**

```
Started POST "/influencerreports" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-29 06:03:07 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant InfluencerreportsController):

activesupport (5.0.7.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.0.7.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.0.7.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
activesupport (5.0.7.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
activesupport (5.0.7.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
actionpack (5.0.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:81:in `controller_class'
actionpack (5.0.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `controller'
actionpack (5.0.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.7.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
```

There's more to the error message, but I felt that wasn't necessary to post up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is called `InfluencerReportsController`, and your error message says the app is looking for a `InfluencerreportsController` controller. Try changing your routes to:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  resources :influencer_reports, only: [:create] do
    resources :photos, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

This should let rails know the correct casing for the controller.

Comment: thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't realize it would think influencerreport is one word if there wasn't an underscore..